# python list of lists contain substring

Tags: python

I have the list_of_lists and I need to get the string that contains 'height' in the sublists and if there is no height at all I need to get 'nvt' for the whole sublist.

I have tried the following:

```
list_of_lists = [['width=9','length=3'],['width=6','length=4','height=4']]

_lists = []

for list in list_of_lists:
    list1 = []
    for st in list:
        if ("height" ) in st:
            list1.append(st)
        else:
            list1.append('nvt')
        _lists.append(list1)

OUT = _lists
```

the result I need to have is :

```
_lists = ['nvt', 'height=4']
```

what I'm getting is:

```
_lists =  [['nvt','nvt'],['nvt','nvt','height=4']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good case for implementing a for/else construct as follows:

```
list_of_lists = [['width=9','length=3'],['width=6','length=4','height=4']]

result = []

for e in list_of_lists:
    for ss in e:
        if ss.startswith('height'):
            result.append(ss)
            break
    else:
        result.append('nvt')
        
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['nvt', 'height=4']
```

**Note:**

This could probably be done with a list comprehension but I think this is more obvious and probably has no significant difference in terms of performance

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you can assign `height` variable to first value in the sublist where `s.startswith("height")` is `True`, and if nothing matches this filter, you can assign `height` to `'nvt'`.

```
_lists = []
for sublist in list_of_lists:
    height = next(filter(lambda s: s.startswith("height"), sublist), 'nvt')
    _lists.append(height)
```

And if you wish to be crazy, you can use list comprehension to reduce the code to the:

```
_lists = [next(filter(lambda s: s.startswith("height"), sublist), 'nvt') for sublist in list_of_lists]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Python 3.x):

```
import re

list_of_lists = [['width=9','length=3'],['width=6','length=4','height=4']]
_lists = []
r = re.compile("height=")
for li in list_of_lists:
    match = list(filter(r.match, li))
    if len(match) > 0:
        _lists.extend(match)
    else:
        _lists.append('nvt')

OUT = _lists
print(OUT)
```